# fadeIn() - why these combination work/not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this CSS :

```
.tracklistOff{display:none;}
.tracklistOn{width:710px; float:left;}
.trackon{width:710px; float:left;}
```

this HTML :

```
<div class="tracklistOff">
    <div class="trackon">
        ... somethings...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, with this code :

```
$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().fadeIn(600).insertAfter('.tracklistOn');
```

I get the `fadeIn()` effect (and this for me is strange; trackon hasn't the `display:none;` attribute).

With this code :

```
$('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().insertAfter('.tracklistOn').fadeIn(600);
```

the fadeIn() effect is not showed. Why changing position on the same elements fadeIn() works or not?

Comment: `tracklistOn` case/captions are different in the script and css.. try matching those..

Comment: Oh no sorry, I just wrong to copy and paste the code here! The code was right on my script!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fadeIn` is a shortcut to `animate({ opacity: "show" })`. In this function there is a condition to check if the current element is visible. If the element is already visible this function does nothing.

Therefore the issue in your code is that in the first example `.trackon` is not visible when `fadeIn` is called, instead in the second one `.trackon` is already visible when `fadeIn` is called so the function does nothing.

```
var working = $('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone();
var notWorking = $('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().insertAfter('.tracklistOn');

console.log(working.is(':hidden')); // true
console.log(notWorking.is(':hidden')); // false
```

Comment: uhm, in fact when I clone it should be visible (is just tracklistOff hidden, not trackon). Maybe is not visible because it isn't added yet! I think I should clone, hide, insert and fade, what do you think?

Comment: In your example, .trackon is not :visible, since it's a child of an hidden element, but seems you're right: if you clone a visible element it is hidden since it isn't appended somewhere in the DOM :P

Comment: `console.log($('body').is(':hidden')); /*false*/
console.log($('body').clone().is(':hidden')); /*true*/`

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks! P.s: strano beccare altri italiani sul portale :)